# Powershell: A parameter cannot be found that matches

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-v4.0

I am new to the Powershell world.  Below is my first script

```
$sServer = "Fully.Qualified.Computer.Name"

$os = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computername $sServer
$object = New-Object –TypeNamePSObject
$object | Add-Member –MemberTypeNoteProperty –Name OSBuild –Value $os.BuildNumber
$object | Add-Member –MemberTypeNoteProperty –Name OSVersion –Value $os.Version
$object | Add-Member –MemberTypeNoteProperty –Name BIOSSerial –Value $bios.SerialNumber
Write-Output $object
```

When I run this script in PowershellISE, I get the following error.

```
New-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TypeNamePSObject'.
At C:\Users\someone\Desktop\SchwansScript.ps1:27 char:22
+ $object = New-Object –TypeNamePSObject
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object],ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Unfortunately for me, it seems like "A parameter cannot be found..." is an extremely common and ambiguous error, saying that there is a problem, but never where. I was wondering if anyone could tell why this error is occuring.  Oh, and I'm on Windows 7 and my PS Version is

```
PS C:\Users\someone> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> New-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'TypeNamePSObject'

It's not ambiguous at all, the error indicates `–TypeNamePSObject` is not a known parameter of the `New-Object` cmdlet.

```
$object = New-Object –TypeNamePSObject
```

Should be instead:

```
$object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject
```

Note the space delimiting the parameter `-TypeName` and the value `PSObject`.

You may use tab completion to discover parameters. In the console, type a cmdlet's name, a space, <kbd>-</kbd>, then <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle through the known parameters. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will reverse the order.

Comment: Made the same error.. just because this MS document has the same error: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh750381.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Would just like to add: it should be: `–MemberType NoteProperty` (space in between).

Otherwise, you get this error:
`Add-Member : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'MemberTypeNoteProperty'`

Comment: This should really be a comment.